# Why am I not seeing all the system settings?

Tags: gnome-control-center, unity-control-center

I just installed Ubuntu for the first time (switched from a Mint), and I'd like to set my preferences, which are, among other things, disabling cleartype altogether and moving some keys around (caps lock, shift and ctrl, just to name them, that's irrelevant to the question).

I found some answers but all suggest that I should see certain tabs in the control center that I'm not seeing. Namely, in the appearance panel, I get no [Fonts](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_Ubuntu_Desktop_Fonts) tab and, in the Keyboard panel, I get no [Layouts](http://mygeekopinions.blogspot.com.br/2011/05/how-to-change-keyboard-layout-in-ubuntu.html) tab.

I tried to run `unity-control-center` as root to no avail. I also tried to STFW and found nothing.

What am I missing ?